# pandas looks for scikits.statsmodels instead of statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have:
statsmodels 0.5.0 (formally known as scikits.statsmodels)
pandas 0.12.0.
(all installed from source)

I get this error:

```
  File "/home/username/.local/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.12.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/stats/ols.py", line 53, in __init__
import scikits.statsmodels.api as sm
ImportError: No module named scikits.statsmodels.api
```

Why is pandas still looking for scikits.statsmodels? Should I install an old version of scikits.statsmodels parallel to statsmodels 0.5.0?

Comment: SOLVED by reinstalling pandas, after statsmodels is allready installed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version 0.12 first tries to import the `statsmodels` library and only if it fails, pandas fall back to the `scikits` module. Here is the piece of code that tries to do that:

```
try:
    import statsmodels.api as sm
except ImportError:
    import scikits.statsmodels.api as sm
```

If you type in the interpreter:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

What error do you get?

Comment: "import statsmodels.api as sm" works fine. Just "scikits.statsmodels.api" fails. One more thing: During the first install, there was weird dependency cycle: statsmodels install demanded to have pandas installed first, but pandas uses statsmodels (optionally). Now I tried reinstalling statsmodels then pandas, but it didn't help.

Comment: Wait it seems to work now. so you have to install pandas after statsmodels

Comment: Statsmodels has pandas as a dependency, so you need to install pandas first. I'm thinking this is something of a local problem. Incidentally, what do you import to trigger this?

Comment: statsmodels doesn't need to (or better, cannot) be installed before installing pandas. But if you want to use pandas functions that use statsmodels, then you need to install it before using it.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the right package.

Just run:

`sudo pip install statsmodels`

Comment: In the case of being in a VM, you probably wouldn't add to this your global environment?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what your question is?

Answer (score 1):

So, I encountered this problem and the reason was statsmodels has a dependency on patsy.

```
try:
    import statsmodels.api as sm
except ImportError:
   import scikits.statsmodels.api as sm
```

When importing statsmodels, not having patsy also throws an ImportError. 
Running

```
easy_install patsy
```

was a fix for this. Not sure why, but pip installed statsmodels without realizing patsy was a dependency.